# How to limit the movement of a circle inside a range?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

I am creating a game in which there will be a map and some svg circle(representing units/troops) with some count on them.Unit move with position of mouse. There is also another circle representing range.

I have two needs

- When the unit is being moved it shouldn't cross its range
- If the mouse is out of range then I want the unit to at the circumference of range circle in direction of mouse. Image to explain second point is below.

[image]

There are two problems

- If I move the unit very quickly it moves out of the range circle.
- If the unit moves out of the circle it didn't move any further.

Below is the snippet. I have explained as much as I could with comments. The most important part for problem is `onMouseMove` in `<Board />`

```js
//helper functions

//to get the difference b/w two array.(Absoulute difference)
const getAbsDist= (arr1,arr2) => arr1.map((x,i) => Math.abs(x - arr2[i]))
//to get diagonal distance coverered from vertical and horizontal distance covered
const getDiaDist = (x,y) => Math.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y)); 
const clone = (obj) => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); //to clone object

class UnitBox extends React.Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    const {
      x, //current vertical postion
      y, //current horizontal position
      count, 
      range, 
      moving, //determines whether a range circle will appear or not
      onMouseDown,
      index,
      //position from which we started moving unit
      _x, 
      _y
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <g className="ub">
        <g
          onMouseDown={() => onMouseDown(index)}
          transform={"translate(" + x + ',' + y + ')'}
        >
          <text id="one" selectable="false">{count}</text>
          <circle r="15" />

          <use xlinkHref="#one" />
        </g>
        {moving && (
          <circle r={range} cx={_x} cy={_y} className="range" />
        )}
      </g>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movingUnit: -1,
    unitBoxes: [
      { moving: false, count: 10, x: 200, y: 100, range: 50 }
    ]
  };
  onMouseDownUnit = unitIndex => {
    const state = clone(this.state),
    unit = state.unitBoxes[unitIndex];
    state.movingUnit = unitIndex;
    unit.moving = true;
    //'_x' and '_y' are the cords from where we click mouse it repesents the initial position
    [unit._x, unit._y] = [unit.x, unit.y]; 
    this.setState(state);
  };
  onMouseUp = e => {
    const state = clone(this.state);
    const unit = state.unitBoxes[this.state.movingUnit];
    state.movingUnit = -1;
    if (unit) unit.moving = false;
    this.setState(state);
  };
  onMouseMove = e => {
    
    let { movingUnit, unitBoxes } = this.state;
    if (movingUnit === -1) return;
    const { clientX, clientY } = e;
    const unit = unitBoxes[movingUnit];
    const { x, y,_x, _y, range} = unit;
    //get the difference b/w initial positon and final position and last final position and get diagonal distance from that.
    let dist = getDiaDist(...getAbsDist([x, y], [_x, _y]));
    
    //if distance covered is less than range than move the object.
    if(dist < range){ 
      unit.x = parseInt(clientX);
      unit.y = parseInt(clientY);
    }
    this.setState({ movingUnit, unitBoxes });
  };
  render() {
    const { unitBoxes } = this.state;
    return (
      <svg
        height="1000px"
        width="1000px"
        onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove}
        onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
        style={{ backgroundColor: "orange" }}
      >
        {unitBoxes.map((x, i) => (
          <UnitBox
            onMouseDown={this.onMouseDownUnit}
            {...x}
            index={i}
            key={i}
          />
        ))}
      </svg>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Board/>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.ub text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    alignment-baseline: central;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    fill: #454545;
}
.ub{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ub circle {
    stroke: #707070;
    fill: #cacaca;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
.ub .range{
    fill:green;
    fill-opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You measure the current distance from the actual position, `dist` with the last updated position of the moving unit, but the position isn't updated when the mouse is outside the valid range. Use the current position of the mouse pointer instead:

```
  let dist = getDiaDist(...getAbsDist([clientX, clientY], [_x, _y]));
```

This change will keep the unit in its range, but it will not update its position when the mouse is moved outside the range. To do this, handle the case where the distance is larger than the range by "clamping" the unit to the range in the direction of the mouse pointer:

```
  if (dist < range) { 
      unit.x = clientX;
      unit.y = clientY;
  } else {
      let xx = clientX;
      let yy = clientY;
      let cc = range / dist;

      unit.x = _x + (xx - _x) * cc;
      unit.y = _y + (yy - _y) * cc;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried the code? The unit will never move out of its range circle. I had tested this in the online thingy before posting, but thought that just posting the problematic section would make for a better answer.